# satchmo nginx redirect to https then to http and back

Tags: python, django, uwsgi, satchmo

Im having a weird issue with a django project called satchmo, Im deploying with nginx and uwsgi.

Whats happening is that the application does respond and it redirects to https and then to http and back to https until nginx stops and the application never responds.

Help me figure out this. Thank you!

this is my sites-available config file for nginx:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name miche.maumercado.com;
   rewrite      ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
        listen 443;
        charset utf-8;
        server_name miche.maumercado.com;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/test.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/cert-EO5rjY;
        access_log /home/ubuntu/logs/miche/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /home/ubuntu/logs/miche/nginx/error.log;
        client_max_body_size 100m;
        location ^~ /static/ {
                alias /home/ubuntu/django-projects/miche_store/static-collect/;
                expires max;
        }

        location ^~ /media/ {
                alias /home/ubuntu/django-projects/miche_store/media/;
                expires max;
        }

        location / {
                uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/uwsgi_miche.sock;
                include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
        }

}
```

This is the uwsgi.conf file in /etc/init:

```
# file: /etc/init/uwsgi_miche.conf
description "uWSGI starter"

start on (local-filesystems and runlevel [2345])
stop on runlevel [016]

respawn

# home - is the path to our virtualenv directory
# pythonpath - the path to our django application
# module - the wsgi handler python script

exec /home/ubuntu/ve/miche_store/bin/uwsgi \
--uid ubuntu \
--pythonpath /home/ubuntu/django-projects/miche_store \
-H /home/ubuntu/ve/miche_store \
--socket /tmp/uwsgi_miche.sock \
--chmod-socket 644 \
--module wsgi \
--logdate \
--optimize 2 \
--processes=6 \
--max-requests=5000 \
--master \
--vacuum \
--logto /home/ubuntu/logs/miche/uwsgi.log
```

And heres my wsgi.py file:

```
import os
import sys
import site

site.addsitedir('/home/ubuntu/ve/miche_store/lib/python2.6/site-packages')
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), '../'))

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'miche_store.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Satchmo includes a piece of middleware called `satchmo_store.shop.SSLMiddleware.SSLRedirect`, which automatically does redirecting to SSL/non-SSL portions of the site. You have to set up URLs to be served via SSL if you want them to be served via SSL, otherwise the middleware redirects to a non-SSL page. From the docs:

> This middleware answers the problem of redirecting to (and from) a SSL secured path
>   by stating what paths should be secured in urls.py file. To secure a path, add the
>   additional view_kwarg 'SSL':True to the view_kwargs.
>
> For example
>
> ```
> urlpatterns = patterns('some_site.some_app.views',
>     (r'^test/secure/$','test_secure',{'SSL':True}),
>      )
> ```
>
> All paths where 'SSL':False or where the kwarg of 'SSL' is not specified are routed
>   to an unsecure path.
>
> For example
>
> ```
> urlpatterns = patterns('some_site.some_app.views',
>     (r'^test/unsecure1/$','test_unsecure',{'SSL':False}),
>     (r'^test/unsecure2/$','test_unsecure'),
>      )
> ```

In your case, since you're serving the entire site via SSL, you can probably just disable that middleware in your `settings.py` file.